# How to map silk 4j script to the test case in Silk Central

Tags: silktest, silk-central

Please suggest on how to map/link silk 4j script to the manual test case written in Silk Central.

Like for 4Test script we select .t file and then the testcase under silk test classic properties in silk central for each test case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your Silk4J tests are in JUnit format, you need to change the manual test case in Silk Central to JUnit type instead of manual. Then specify the fully qualified name (including package) of your JUnit test as Test class. In the classpath you need to specify all jar files that are needed for executing the test.

Answer (score 1):

The test type can be changed in the Tests unit from the context menu of a node. Use the action "Automate with ...". Choose the appropriate type, e.g. "Silk Test Classic Test" for .t-files or "JUnit Test" if you use silk4j.

Regards,
Hubert